# Symfony3 customizing error pages (404, 403...)

Tags: twig, symfony, symfony-3.1

I don't know what is wrong but I couldn't override the error pages as [describe](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html#main) in the documentation by simply create the related file at `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error.404.html.twig` or `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error.403.html.twig` and so on...
Notice that I also clean the cache as well before check it: `bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`. I'm using Symfony 3.0.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the twig file name should be:

```
error404.html.twig
```

**not**:

```
error.404.html.twig
```

Let me know if you still have problems. This should work, because I've used it.